# WPF Project with Custom XAML Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am new to WPF coding. I have a project that has custom controls coded as xaml's with C# code-behinds. I try to import these files into another project and when I try to use these xaml controls in my main view file, Visual Studio cannot find the namespace that the imported xaml's and C# code-behinds are attached to.

I tried changing the namespace to be the same as my current project. I tried restarting Visual Studio 2013. Neither of these worked.

I tried adding the project with the custom controls to my solution. The imported project can read the custom xaml's, but my main project still can't reference them. I tried dragging the files over to the main project, and they still won't work.

I tried rebuilding the controls xaml's and C# code-behinds in my new project it still says:

The type 'local:ClickSelectTextBox' was not found. Please verify that that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all reference assemblies have been built.

This item is under the appropriate namespace and in the current project.

Comment: did you add the `xmlns:controls_namespace` directive?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Visual Studio cannot find the namespace"?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "The imported project can read the custom xaml's"? Do you mean the project in which the custom controls are in?

Comment: There are many tutorials online for writing custom control projects for WPF.  Use those.

Comment: Yes, I have done those tutorials. I am missing something. I tried rebuilding the controls xaml's and C# code-behinds in my new project it still says:

Comment: The type 'local:Atdl_ClickSelectTextBox' was not found. Please verify that that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all reference assemblies have been built.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio go to TOOLS -> choose Toolbox Items. this will allow you either choose from an array of different components or browse around to find a dll that you would like to use.

EDIT:

Oh so you are trying to take customized xaml files that you already have written and modify them in a separate project? I would suggest one of two things.

1: right click your project name -> add existing, and add the xaml and xaml.cs file to your project at the same time.

if for some reason that does not work you can also try

2: creating a new xaml control (with the same name of the control you want to drop in) in your project and copy pasting the xaml code into that control, this should autogenerate the codebehind designer shell you are going to need. you can then go into the xaml.cs file and drop whatever business logic you are looking for. It is not the cleanest solution but sometimes the WPF editor gets a little funky when importing xaml files

Comment: I am trying to add the xaml and C# code behind files so that I can customize them. I cannot do this. I get the error:

Comment: The type 'local:ClickSelectTextBox' was not found. Please verify that that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all reference assemblies have been built.

Comment: I tried adding the controls under the Toolbox as well, and they all throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but still somebody may find it useful:) So! ... Make sure

1)You don't have public class outside of root namespace, check this
[link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/10/31/why-does-the-xaml-designer-report-that-my-custom-elements-have-not-been-built/)

2)You are not mixing targets of your assemblies (unless you can't 100% avoid that)

For example, if you are referencing something like SQLite.Core NuGet (that has both x86 and x64 versions of SQLite.Interop.dll built in) in a project that is AnyCPU, sometimes it's easier to set application's target to x86 or x64 to solve the x86/x64 paths issues - but then you may get all these "type not found/control not built/assembly not found" and all that sorts of nonsense from Designer even despite your app builds and runs ok.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading ReSharper's trial version, install it and then open up your code again. One of the awesome features Resharper has with XAML code is that it will automatically map objects to their appropriate namespace. I think this will make it easier for you and will show you a ton of ways to do things better. When I was first learning WPF it was honestly a godsend to use Resharper.